# file_get_contents() misses some important data

Tags: php, web-crawler

I'm trying to read the html from [this page](http://nutritiondata.self.com/facts/fruits-and-fruit-juices/1848/2) to later parse it. The problem is when I use `file_get_contents($url)`, it misses some content (the content I actually need). For example, it doesn't get the data after "Amounts per 1 ounce" (just a blank), and all the data (the numbers only, it does get the labels) in the "NUTRITION INFORMATION" tables.

Here's the script:

```
<?php
$url = "http://nutritiondata.self.com/facts/fruits-and-fruit-juices/1848/2";
$content = file_get_contents($url);
var_dump($content);
?>
```

Comment: visit the page without javascript, that's what file_get_contents will get. there might be ajax calls or data encoded in javascript.

Comment: `file_get_contents` just gets the page's source code.  It doesn't run any JavaScript code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL you are requesting does not actually contain the data you're looking for.  The data you see in your browser is being put into the page via javascript.

Here's what the page looks like without javascript:

[image: page with javascript disabled]

You'll need to find the datasource the javascript is using (which is probably some other URL entirely) and read that.

It looks like in this case, the data *is* actually in the page you're requesting (just not where you're looking for it), in a big JSON object around line 3400. Look for     `foodNutrients = {`

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that the page does get build partly from javascript. If you visit the page and let you show the HTML code (not via a DOM inspector or something, but the actually source of the page) you can see, that the part you are searching for is not available.

There's quite a lot of javascript included in the page and you will probably have to find out, which of the javascript fills the page and where it get's it's data from.

"file_get_contents" won't help you with this, because the javascript part will never be executed.